# WCF Streaming proxy in UWP app

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp, streaming

I have to write a WCF service to transfer large files (500MB - 3GB) to a UWP client. I've configured the service as a streaming service which works perfectly fine when i generate the client proxy on a console application. My download method looks like this:

```
public Stream GetFile(GetFileRequest request)
```

When i generate the client proxy in the uwp app, the response of the GetFile Method turns into a byte[] and it looks like the download process is not streamed than transfered as one piece of byte[].

Here's the web.config of the service:

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streamedBinding" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="10:00:00" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Even if set the binding manually at the client before making the call

```
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
                {
                    CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                    TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.StreamedResponse
                };
```

it doesen't change anything. Also I'm awaiting the client call

```
await client.GetFileAsync(fileRequest)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean, if you are using the uwp app as client, the file data are not be partially received? If on that case, what is the size of the one piece of byte[]? Can it be downloaded successfully? If I misunderstand you please kindly tell me more details.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT yes exactly. It looks like the getFile method blocks until all data is received. I tried it with a 26MB file. Also a 1.5GB file cant be downloaded, it throws an exception after a couple of minutes. I wasnt able to retrieve the exception due to visual studio problems.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy Somehow yes - I ended up implemented the download by chunking the files into 10 MB pieces by myself.

Comment: I meant it still returns a byte array or stream?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy still an byte array